# Unable to build Android app (created with Ionic framework) after importing the project into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm a complete beginner at creating mobile apps. I created an Ionic mobile app for Android using Windows and Visual Studio 2017. It works when I use the ionic serve command and try the app in the browser.

But when I try to import the project into Android Studio 2.3.3, I get an error message, that it can't build my app:
"Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: ...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Gradle sync completed.
Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)."

I also get another error message after importing the project into Android Studio, when I try to run the "ionic cordova run android" command in cmd: "An error occured while running cordova run android. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Where: ...\cordova.gradle line 64

What went wrong:
A problem occured evaluating root project 'android'. No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0  or higher."

I imported the files into Android Studio choosing Import project (Eclipse,...). I chose this folder when importing:
node_modules\cordova-android\spec\fixtures\android_project. I'm not sure this is the right folder to choose.

I can see the simulated android phone , I can click on everything, but my app doesn't show up on it. 
I checked the Android build tools, 25.0.3 and 26.0.2 are installed.
Thank you for the help in advance! I'm really stuck :S﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are choosing Wrong Folder.

To open your ionic generated app. You need to open the following folder in the path:

```
Your_ionic_project/platforms/android
```

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where: myAPP/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 64

What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

Comment: Installed build tools (in this folder: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\builder): 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 
2.3.2, 2.3.3

Comment: In C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\sdk-common folder:

25.3.0, 

25.3.1, 

25.3.2, 

25.3.3,

Comment: I got this "Build failed" error message after I imported the files into Android Studio choosing Import project (Eclipse,...). I chose this folder when importing: myAPP/platforms/android

Comment: What was your last Build fail Error ?

Comment: If your aim is to build the Android App from the Ionic project. You can use CLI commands instead of Importing the project in Studio. For building the APK ionic CLI command : " ionic cordova build android "

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set your system PATH variable pointing to android platform tools.

Something like :

```
C:\Users\Lokkeshwaran J\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Comment: Thanx, these are my environment variables:                                    
ANDROID_HOME: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\sdklib\25.3.3                                               
GRADLE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2   Path: C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\lib;                                                       
Are these correct?

Comment: See my Latest answer